# Oracle equivalent of Postgres' DISTINCT ON?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

In postgres, you can query for the first value of in a group with `DISTINCT ON`. **How can this be achieved in Oracle?**

From the postgres manual:

> SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of
>   each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. The
>   DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for
>   ORDER BY (see above). Note that the "first row" of each set is
>   unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row
>   appears first.

For example, for a given table:

```
 col1 | col2 
------+------
 A    | AB
 A    | AD
 A    | BC
 B    | AN
 B    | BA
 C    | AC
 C    | CC
```

Ascending sort:

```
> select distinct on(col1) col1, col2 from tmp order by col1, col2 asc;
 col1 | col2 
------+------
 A    | AB
 B    | AN
 C    | AC
```

Descending sort:

```
> select distinct on(col1) col1, col2 from tmp order by col1, col2 desc;
 col1 | col2 
------+------
 A    | BC
 B    | BA
 C    | CC
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The same effect can be replicated in Oracle either by using the [`first_value()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions059.htm) function or by using one of the [`rank()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions129.htm#SQLRF00690) or [`row_number()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions144.htm#SQLRF06100) functions.

Both variants also work in Postgres.

**`first_value()`**

```
select distinct col1, 
first_value(col2) over (partition by col1 order by col2 asc)
from tmp
```

`first_value` gives the first value for the partition, but repeats it for each row, so it is necessary to use it in combination with `distinct` to get a single row for each partition.

**`row_number()` / `rank()`**

```
select col1, col2 from (
  select col1, col2, 
  row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2 asc) as rownumber 
  from tmp
) foo
where rownumber = 1
```

Replacing `row_number()` with `rank()` in this example yields the same result.

A feature of this variant is that it can be used to fetch the **first N** rows for a given partition (e.g. "last 3 updated") simply by changing `rownumber = 1` to `rownumber <= N`.

Comment: +1: The `first_value()` variant is quite a clever simulation of `DISTINCT ON`. I should build that into [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org)

Comment: How to apply this if I want DISTINCT from 2 fields and corresponding values from all other fields?

Comment: @tumchaaditya - use the ROW_NUMBER() function!

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than two fields then use beerbajays answer as a sub query (note in DESC order):

```
select col1,col2, col3,col4 from tmp where col2 in
(
select distinct 
first_value(col2) over (partition by col1 order by col2 DESC) as col2
from  tmp
--WHERE you decide conditions
)
```