# Query with multiple joins and optional parameters

Tags: database, oracle, performance

I have something of a Search App. There are 7 fields (first name, last name, phone, street, city, shop number, credit card number) where user can write parameters and it's gonna find him clients in the database. Everything is working with AND condition, so when first name is 'Andy' and last name is 'Larkin' is only gonna find Andy Larkins etc. User can leave a field empty, that means when first name is 'Andy' then it should find all the Andys etc. Database looks like this:

[image]

The 'Relation' table is to connect person and a shop. Person must have 1 address, 1 shop, can have multiple addresses, multiple shops and no credit card/multiple credit cards. Now, I have to handle all the filtering in a single query, I can't check some conditions before and then construct the query another way, I just don't have that option.

When I search by first name or last name it's fast (both in Person table), but when I search by phone number, or credit card number - it's taking a lot of time. There is a lot of data in the database, but still, my query is bad, I'm not really good at writing queries, especially in Oracle. Here's the query:

```sql
SELECT
    PERSON.personId,
    PERSON.firstName,
    PERSON.lastName
    ADDRESS.street,
    ADDRESS.city,
    ADDRESS.phoneNumber
FROM
    PERSON
    LEFT JOIN ADDRESS ON PERSON.personId = ADDRESS.personId,
    LEFT JOIN RELATION ON PERSON.personId = RELATION.personId,
    LEFT JOIN SHOPS ON RELATION.shopId = SHOPS.shopId
    LEFT JOIN CREDITCARDS ON PERSON.personId = CREDITCARDS.personId
WHERE
    PERSON.firstName = NVL(?, PERSON.firstName),
    PERSON.lastName = NVL(?, PERSON.lastName),
    ADDRESS.phoneNumber = NVL(?, ADDRESS.phoneNumber),
    ADDRESS.street = NVL(?, ADDRESS.street),
    ADDRESS.city = NVL(?, ADDRESS.city),
    SHOPS.shopNumber = NVL(?, SHOPS.shopNumber),
    CREDITCARDS.creditCardNumber = NVL(?, CREDITCARDS.creditCardNumber);
```

The parameters that user left empty are passed as NULLS, that's why I use NVL. When I delete all conditions and leave let's say a credit card number, then it's fast, so I guess that means that all the unnecessary condition checking is slowing the query, and I don't really need that condition checking in most cases, it's just there in case a user passes something.

If I would have the option to check for conditions and only then construct a query then I would just add the conditions that are needed, but I don't have that option. I was thinking about adding some 'IFs' in the query, but I'm not sure that's even possible, all I could find was 'IF/CASE WHEN' but couldn't find any examples that apply to my case. I also tried this:

`...WHERE (? IS NULL OR (PERSON.firstName = NVL(?, PERSON.firstName))) AND...`

That didn't help, and I got tons of duplicated (different only in address or something - person can have multiple addresses) results (even with 'DISTINCT').

It's not homework, that database is huge with lot of other fields, but I simplified it here, there is also a lot of data there. Thanks for help.

Comment: You say a person always has 1 address and shop so remove the outer join on ADDRESS and SHOP

Comment: Unrelated - the left joins will not work as left join as nulls will be ignored by your where clause.. It'll be as if those are inner joins

Comment: Is your primary key for address, credit card, etc, a surrogate primary keys or natural one? If natural then having an index on the PersonId, ShopId might help.

Comment: btw I tried this query with different kinds of joins, didn't help, some made things worse

Comment: @RichBianco Those are surrogate keys. I would like to solve this problem by fixing the query if there is a possibility.

Comment: @Whatz - I understand you don't want to fix database however not knowing what the PK and Indexes are make it difficult to answer.Also noticed your Relation table is a natural key so thought they might all be natural. If you could run an explain plan and attach it would help a lot.

Comment: @RichBianco What about the second option I mentioned ('WHERE (? IS NULL OR (...)))') - I could deal with performance of that, but like I said, lot's of duplicated results, is there some way to get rid of them? Tried some tricks like for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350452/distinct-on-one-column-only-in-oracle, but they either didn't work or query was a lot longer. Something like `DISTINCT(personId)` would be perfect, but I guess it doesn't exist in Oracle.

Comment: @Whatzs Duplication of data is normal with joining relational tables and Oracle should handle it fine- you shouldn't need to help Oracle there. Considering there's a lot of data like you said- the only thing that might help is using Oracle hints (assuming no indexing changes). I'll be watching this to see if anyone can solve without index changes.

Comment: @RichBianco Yes duplication is expected, but is there no way to limit the final results? I'm getting 10 persons and they are all 'the same', same person displayed with all of his 10 adresses, is that unavoidable?

Answer (score 1):

A few things to think about here.

1. Be careful about queries that might not make sense; such as those that query a credit card number and an address. Queries of that nature fall into a fan trap.
2. Creating referential integrity constraints in the database will allow the optimizer to do join elimination.
3. It would be much better for the optimizer, if you could build the query "where clause" dynamically, rather than using NVL functions.

Answer (score 0):

A nested select on the shops might improve performance especially considering it's outer joined. The query below should be enough to get you the idea.

Regarding de-duplication- it's hard because you are selecting Id's and 'distinct' won't help. You'd probably have to use the group by syntax and that might slow the query even more.

If sorting can be done on the client it might help with performance. If the amount of data being returned is significant due to fan-out of relational data and group by isn't a good option then creating a stored procedure might be the best option so most the work is done on database and minimal data over the wire.

```
SELECT
    p.personId,
    p.firstName,
    a.city,
    a.phoneNumber,
    shop.shopNumber
FROM
   PERSON p,
   ADDRESS a,
   CREDITCARDS c,
   (select ss.personId, ss.shopId, ss.shopNumber from shop s, relation r
       where s.shopId = r.shopId) as shop
WHERE
   p.personId = a.personId AND
   p.personId = c.personId AND
   p.personId = shop.personId (+)
```