# How to get only one record for each duplicate rows of the id in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

suppose i have this table:

```
group_id | image | image_id |
-----------------------------
23        blob       1
23        blob       2
23        blob       3
21        blob       4
21        blob       5
25        blob       6
25        blob       7
```

how to get results of only 1 of each group id? in this case,there may be multiple images for one group id, i just want one result of each **group_id**

i tried distinct but i will only get group_id. max for image also would not work.

Comment: I don't know oracle, do you have `distinct on (group_id)` ?

Comment: Do you care which `blob` will be chosen?  I suggest that you post the query that you tried and the expected result based on your data sample,

Comment: Do you care which row for each group id you get?

Comment: Found similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515391/oracle-equivalent-of-postgres-distinct-on

Comment: @some : there's no distinct on for oracle if im not mistaken and the link you gave when i tried it gave me my some error which is inconsistent datatypes expected - got blob

Comment: @PM77-1 : i dont mind which blob. as long as i get one record for each group id.

Comment: @OldProgrammer : i dont mind which blob. as long as i get one record for each group id.

Comment: @Psychocryo `distinct on` is a postgresql extension, and the link I gave you was had an answer of how to do that in oracle. Sorry that it didn't work for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle equivalent of Postgres' DISTINCT ON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515391/oracle-equivalent-of-postgres-distinct-on)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are **no** standard aggregate functions in Oracle that would work with `BLOB`s, so `GROUP BY` solutions won't work.

Try this one based on `ROW_NUMBER()` in a sub-query.

```
SELECT inn.group_id, inn.image, inn.image_id
FROM
(
    SELECT t.group_id, t.image, t.image_id, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.group_id ORDER BY t.image_id) num
    FROM theTable t
) inn
WHERE inn.num = 1;
```

The above should return the first (based on `image_id`) row for each group.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff076/1)

Comment: i've tried using max but my problem is that it wont work for blob. i get an error like this --> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB

Comment: What is the datatype for image column?

Comment: Do you need such query as a report or will it become a part of `INSERT` or `UPDATE`?

Comment: the datatype is blob. i will use it to create a view. where it will list only one blob record for one group_id. i just needed one for different purposes. as long as i can get a query to get listing of only one record for each group_id, that will suffice.

Comment: OK. Working on a different method. Will post the script shortly.

Comment: Thanks @PM 77-1 . i got what i wanted and ur solution worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  group_id, image, image_id
FROM    a_table
WHERE   (group_id, image_id) IN
        (
            SELECT  group_id, MIN(image_id)
            FROM    a_table
            GROUP   BY
                    group_id
        )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
  (select t1.*,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id desc) as seqnum
   from tablename t1) 
where seqnum=1;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.