# select distinct on one column with multiple columns returned in oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

After querying with

```
partition by Id order by Id asc on my table Tbl
```

I get the result:

```
Id      DATE&TIME               DATE       VALUE
A      03-05-2015,03:05:36  03-05-2015  2
B      19-05-2015,11:05:02  19-05-2015  2
A      15-05-2015,06:05:38  15-05-2015  2
A      15-05-2015,09:05:06  15-05-2015  8
A      15-05-2015,09:05:29  15-05-2015  10
A      15-05-2015,11:05:18  15-05-2015  10
c      05-05-2015,02:05:15  03-05-2015  20
d      12-05-2015,03:05:28  08-05-2015  2
d      12-05-2015,04:05:56  07-05-2015  10
e      04-05-2015,08:05:41  03-05-2015  2
f      06-05-2015,09:05:35  08-05-2015  20
```

but I require output like:

```
Id    DATE&TIME             VALUE
A     03-05-2015,03:05:36   2
B     19-05-2015,11:05:02   2
A     15-05-2015,11:05:18   10
c     05-05-2015,02:05:15   20
d     12-05-2015,04:05:56   10
e     04-05-2015,08:05:41   2
f     06-05-2015,09:05:35   20
```

i.e the record should be unique with respect to 'DATE' only & get maximum of 'VALUE' from above data.

Comment: Looks like you should use `group by` on `Id` and `VALUE` and `max` on `DATE&TIME`

Comment: Please show us your **complete** statement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want functionality similar to postgres' `DISTINCT ON`.

Per [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515391/oracle-equivalent-of-postgres-distinct-on), you can use:

```
select distinct id, 
first_value(datetime) over (partition by id order by value desc)
from mytable
```

This is making the assumption that you **do not** want `order by id asc` since for the same ids (e.g. `A`) the order will be unspecified; in the example given the results are therefore sorted by `value desc`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `SELECT DISTINCT ID, TIME, VALUE FROM (partition by Id & order by Id asc on my table Tbl)`

I'm not sure if that syntax works for OracleDB...

The SELECT - Parameters in my query should return the desired columns.

As for the TIME vs. DATE&TIME: If you take a closer look your rows are distinct if you select by DATE&TIME your desired result indicates, that you want DISTINCT entries for the DATE...