# Order by only one, of two distinct columns

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am selecting ColA and ColB in the same statement:

```
select distinct ColA, ColB, EDITABLE from TableA;
```

I would like to use `ORDER BY lower(ColA)`, because I would like to sort ColA alphabetically, without taking capitalization into consideration. ColB does not need to be affect in this sorting and I would like to only sort ColA (which needs to be distinct because there are many instances of the same value in ColA).

I tried

```
select distinct ColA, ColB, EDITABLE
from TableA
ORDER BY lower(ColA)
```

and also saw [this question concerning distinct and order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391564/how-to-use-distinct-and-order-by-in-same-select-statement) but when I tried

```
select distinct ColA, ColB, lower(ColA), EDITABLE
from TableA
GROUP BY ColA
ORDER BY lower(ColA) ASC, ColA
```

I was unable to run the statement above. I am very new at SQL and would love some tips on why this didn't work and help on what I can improve this statement on

Comment: "I was unable to run the statement above" Did you get a error?

Comment: Yes - running it Oracle SQL Developer results in: "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: "there are many instances of the same value in ColA" - are there many instances of the *combination* of ColA, ColB and editable? Distinct applies to the whole row in the result set, not a single column.

Comment: @AlexPoole it feels like the topicstarter wants to do   `DISTINCT ON(ColA), ColB, lower(ColA), EDITABLE` (PostgreSQL syntax) and get unique `ColA` values for `ColB, lower(ColA), EDITABLE` columns. Topicstarter see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515391/oracle-equivalent-of-postgres-distinct-on)

Comment: Possibly, yes. Sample data and expected results would help, of course...

Comment: Why do you want to use the `group by` approach instead of the `distinct` approach anyway? You aren't doing any aggregation, and you'll get the same result if you group by all of the columns you're selecting - but that's more code and it's less clear what the intent is. Having to suppress duplicates at all might suggest a problem with your data, but if you have a legitimate reason, what's wrong with the `distinct` keyword - that's what it's for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mention all the columns in the `Group By` that you are `Select`ing

In SQLServer, it is like:

```
select distinct ColA, ColB, lower(ColA)
from TableA
GROUP BY ColA, ColB, lower(ColA)
ORDER BY lower(ColA) ASC
```

Comment: Most likely this will give a different result which the topicstarter is after.

Comment: The `distinct` keyword is redundant - the group-by has the same effect.

Comment: Thanks! Worked but I made the statement a bit shorter and it did the same trick for me `select ColA, ColB, EDITABLE from TableA GROUP BY ColA, ColB, EDITABLE ORDER BY lower(ColA) ASC`

Comment: My answer was the first one. Still not accepted as 'answer' @Jedo :'( 
nvm, happy coding :)

Comment: @Jedo - you don't have to accept the first answer; [accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I don't like this answer. What is the `GROUP BY` for? You can remove it; it makes no sense.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Please read Jedo's above comment. It solved his problem :)

Comment: @AlexPoole Please read Jedo's above comment. It solved his problem :)

Comment: Your query applies `DISTINCT` on the rows. The `GROUP BY` does exactly the same, only that it suggests that you wanted to apply some aggregation (`MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`, `COUNT`, whatever). You don't.  You even have exactly the same columns in `GROUP BY` and after `DISTINCT` which indicates that it cannot remove any duplicates from the list. So all in all, you are suggesting a query that looks faulty, because of superfluous and inappropriate elements. Your proposed query is not good and your explanation of how to use `GROUP BY` is misleading. Hence my downvote.

Comment: Sort of - after some editing. Getting the desired output - and this doesn't quite, from Jedo's comment - doesn't make it completely right, or the best approach. The first sentence sort of covers the issue - at least the error Jedo was getting - but the fix isn't ideal. My issue though was with your suggestion in a comment that this should be accepted because it was first. It's up to the question asker which answer (if any) they accept, being first shouldn't be a significant factor.

Answer (score 2):

Your referenced question does not apply to your question.  In that question, there is *another* column used for ordering, one not in the original `select distinct`.  In your case, the `order by` is using a function on one of the original columns.  There should be no need to repeat the expression in the `SELECT`.

You can also use `group by`:

```
select ColA, ColB, EDITABLE
from TableA
group by ColA, ColB, EDITABLE
order by lower(ColA);
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is the accepted answer. Isn't `EDITABLE` a column of `TableA`? Then we'd have to use an aggregate function on it, but this is not requested. So we'd put it in `GROUP BY` instead, but then we can remove the whole `GROUP BY` clause, add `DISTINCT` and end up exactly with the query Jedo has already shown in their request. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 2):

This is your query:

```
select distinct ColA, ColB, lower(ColA), EDITABLE
from TableA
GROUP BY ColA
ORDER BY lower(ColA) ASC, ColA
```

And this is what it does:

```
1.   FROM clause: select rows from TableA.
2.   GROUP BY clause: Aggregate rows so as to get one row per ColA.
3.   SELECT clause:
3.1.   Show ColA. This is okay, ColA is what you group by.
3.2.   Show ColB. Which? There can be diferent ColB per ColA. This produces an error.
3.3.   Show lower(ColA). That is okay. You group by ColA, so lower(ColA) is also known.
3.4.   Show EDITABLE. Again: which? There can be diferent EDITABLE per ColA.
3.5.   DISTINCT: remove duplicate rows. This is superfluous, because there cannot be
       duplicate rows. They all have different ColA.
4.   ORDER BY clause:
4.1.   Sort by lower(ColA), so you have 'John' and 'john' together.
4.2.   Sort by ColA. This tells the DBMS whther to put 'John' or 'john' first.
```

I hope this explains how a query gets executed, what `GROUP BY` does and what is allowed in the `SELECT` clause. `DISTINCT` is very often a sign for a badly written query. Here it's merely superfluous, but quite often it is used as some defense against poor joins leading to duplicate rows. Whenever you see `SELECT DISTINCT` ask yourself what makes it necessary.