# Remove Duplicate Rows/Data

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, duplicate-data

I'm not quite sure if this topic has already been answered. I saw one post that has almost the same question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442321/how-to-return-only-1-row-if-multiple-duplicate-rows-and-still-return-rows-that-a)) as mine but it still doesn't give me the perfect solution to my problem...

[Here](http://s697.photobucket.com/user/sohotzac/media/Image1.png.html) is the snapshot of the report I'm having problem with :

[image]

Right clicking on the objects in Crystal Report and setting 'Suppress IF Duplicated' doesn't help, though it works with the all of the other fields (as you can see they aren't duplicated)...

Any help would be appreciated. THANKS.

Query from comments:

```
SELECT b.BusinessID, a.AccoID, b.CatID, b.BusinessName, b.Address, 
       b.OwnerName, b.ContactPerson, b.ContactNo, b.MunicipalityID, 
       b.YearEstablished, b.TotalEmployees, ar.RoomName, ar.RoomTotal, 
       ar.RoomCapacity, ar.RoomRate, h.HallName, h.HallCapacity, h.Rate 
FROM dbo.Accommodation AS a 
INNER JOIN dbo.BusinessRecord AS b ON a.BusinessID = b.BusinessID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.AccoRoomDtl AS ar ON a.AccoID = ar.AccoID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.AccoHallDtl AS h ON a.AccoID = h.AccoID
```

Comment: What does your join/query statement look like

Comment: SELECT     b.BusinessID, a.AccoID, b.CatID, b.BusinessName, b.Address, b.OwnerName, b.ContactPerson, b.ContactNo, b.MunicipalityID, b.YearEstablished, 
b.TotalEmployees, ar.RoomName, ar.RoomTotal, ar.RoomCapacity, ar.RoomRate, h.HallName, h.HallCapacity, h.Rate
FROM         dbo.Accommodation AS a INNER JOIN dbo.BusinessRecord AS b ON a.BusinessID = b.BusinessID LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.AccoRoomDtl AS ar ON a.AccoID = ar.AccoID LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.AccoHallDtl AS h ON a.AccoID = h.AccoID

Comment: where are you placing the duplicate ones in the report? I mean in which section?

Comment: @user3571271 it is likely your left outer joins that are causing the problem.  This really isn't duplicated data as they are distinct record rows.  What does your table structure look like, and what is the purpose of the query