# Stop returning multiple similar rows on joins

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, join, distinct

I have the following scenario in SQLite.

```
TableA 

ID
-----
1   |
2   |
3   |


Table B

ID  | AID   |Tag
----------------
1   | 1     | Hide 
2   | 1     | Show
3   | 2     | Null
4   | 3     | Show
```

Table B has column AID which is the IDs of table A.

In the example above 
    Table A ID: '1' has 
        -> Table B ID of '1' and '2' and Tags 'Hide' and 'Show' attached to it.

I am looking for an SQL that will only return, in the example above, Table A IDs: '2' and '3'. 
Basically, as TableA ID: '1' has a 'Hide' tag attached to it, don't return it (even though it also has a show tag attached to it)

The SQL I am using is (excuses the names, this is just a quick example)

```
select 
        a.ID    as a_ID,
        b.ID    as b_ID,
        b.Tag   as Tag
    from
        Table A as a
    left join Table B on a.id = b.aID
        and b.tag != 'hide'
```

The problem with this SQL it's still returning

```
a_ID    | b_ID  | Tag
-------------------------------
1       | 2     | Show
```

I'm a tad stuck and any help would be really appreciated. I'm not 100% sure how I would work this on for a google search. 
The closest I got was this question [How to return only 1 row if multiple duplicate rows and still return rows that are not duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442321/how-to-return-only-1-row-if-multiple-duplicate-rows-and-still-return-rows-that-a)
but I couldn't work out how the GROUP BY would help here.

Comment: Try `select ... where AID not in (select AID from B where Tag = 'Hide')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an extra condition with the `exists` operator:

```
SELECT    a.ID AS a_ID, b.ID AS b_ID, b.Tag AS Tag
FROM      table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.aID
WHERE     NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM   table_b bin
                      WHERE  bin.aID = a.ID AND bin.Tag = 'hide')
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. This worked perfectly thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for an `id` where no row exists with a 'hide' tag. This is a direct translation into SQL:

```
select *
from TableA as a
where not exists
 (
   select * 
   from TableB as B 
   where a.id = b.aID
     and b.tag = 'hide' 
 )
```

Or, if you want the data from TableB:

```
select *
from TableB as t1
where not exists
 (
   select * 
   from TableB as t2 
   where t1.aID = t2.aID
     and t2.tag = 'hide' 
 )
```

Comment: Typed this in wrong and thought it wasn't working! Works perfectly thank you.