# get 1 row from multiple rows MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to achieve a SQL statement where I can get the number of installments from multiple same installments and also get 1 duedate from all duedates and sum the rest rows up.
Here is my Table in a picture.

[image]

What I want to achieve is this.
it will return me rows like

```
instalmentnbr | duedate    | capitalpayment      | interest_payment 
      1       2017-04-13    sum(capitalpayment) sum(interest_payment )
      2       2017-05-13    sum(capitalpayment)  sum(interest_payment )
      3       2017-06-12    sum(capitalpayment)  sum(capitalpayment)
```

So basically getting the 3 installments with their duedate and suming up the rest.

Here is my code.

```
select a.instalmentnbr, a.duedate, sum(a.capital_payment), sum(a.interest_payment), sum(a.overdue_payment)
from helltable a
where a.request_orig_id = 46  order by a.instalmentnbr;
```

I was checking out this example but I really dint get how to it works. 
[How to return only 1 row if multiple duplicate rows and still return rows that are not duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442321/how-to-return-only-1-row-if-multiple-duplicate-rows-and-still-return-rows-that-a)

Comment: Easy, just group on instalmentbr and duedate.

Comment: @OctoCode Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use GROUP BY:

```
select a.instalmentnbr, a.duedate, sum(a.capital_payment), sum(a.interest_payment), sum(a.overdue_payment)
from helltable a
where a.request_orig_id = 46  
group by a.instalmentnbr, a.duedate
order by a.instalmentnbr;
```

Comment: No problems!  Don't forget to mark it as the answer if it worked out for you.

Comment: Yes will do, just waiting for the timer to go away.